# Swift Protocol Oriented Programing causes Xcode to loop the 'fix it'

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have 2 generic abstract:

```
protocol NavigationDelegate: class { }
```

and

```
protocol ViewModelDelegate: class { }
```

And then I have a more elaborated ViewModel protocol:

```
protocol ViewModel: class {
    associatedtype ViewModelDelegateConformance: ViewModelDelegate
    associatedtype NavigationDelegateConformance: NavigationDelegate

    init(delegate: ViewModelDelegateConformance, navigationDelegate: NavigationDelegateConformance)
}
```

Then I have 2 protocols each conforms with the first two, respectively

```
protocol AnyNavigationDelegate: NavigationDelegate {
    func anySelected(for post: Any)
}
```

and

```
protocol AnyViewModelDelegate: ViewModelDelegate {
    func someViewModelAnyUpdated(viewModel: SomeViewModel)
    func someViewModelFailedUpdate(viewModel: SomeViewModel)
}
```

Then I have my ViewModel class

```
class SomeViewModel: ViewModel {
    typealias ViewModelDelegateConformance = AnyViewModelDelegate
    typealias NavigationDelegateConformance = AnyNavigationDelegate

    required init(delegate: ViewModelDelegateConformance, navigationDelegate: NavigationDelegateConformance) {

    }

}
```

But I keep getting the error: SomeViewModel doesn't conform with ViewModel.
When I click in the fix it, it just pops up the type aliases